# Understanding in string concatenation

Tags: c#, string, string-concatenation

I have written the following code where `IsClear`, `IsPermanent` and `IsSalaried` are true. `IsSalaried` is a nullable boolean. I am expecting an output like `"Clear,Permanent,Salaried"` . But it gives the output as `"Clear"` only. Can anybody please help me understand this following concept:

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        MyClass Employee = new MyClass();
        Employee.IsClear = true;
        Employee.IsPermanent = true;
        Employee.IsSalaried = true;

        string Test =  
             Employee.IsClear ? "Clear" : ""
            + (Employee.IsPermanent ? "Permanent" : "") 
            + (Employee.IsSalaried.HasValue ? "Salaried" : "");

        Console.WriteLine(Test);
    }
}

public class MyClass
{
    public bool IsClear { get; set; }
    public bool IsPermanent { get; set; }
    public bool? IsSalaried { get; set; }
}
```

Thanks in advance !!

Comment: `IsClear,IsPermanent,IsSalaried are true` <-- this statement is not true.

Comment: @vivek: Here you are [?: Operator (C# Reference)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx). Hope this help.

Comment: @sstan All are true only . But still unable to get the desired output ..

Comment: @vivek: You'll have to provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (emphasis on `Complete`) to allow us to reproduce what you are seeing.  As pointed out in one answer, your posted code doesn't even compile.

Comment: @sstan what compiler error you are getting  ? I am not getting any error with the above code only the output is not as expected.

Comment: @vivek: Just like Adil pointed out, I get `Use of unassigned local variable 'Test'`.  That's why you need to post a small but complete program that illustrates your problem.  Right now, we don't see the definition of `Employee`.  We don't see where the 3 variables get set, etc...

Comment: Your code doesn't even compile, see this: https://dotnetfiddle.net/Fm9CYs, there's no way your code gives `"Clear"` as the output. I'm voting to close this question since the output of the code is different from what you say in the question.

Comment: @ekad . Thanks a lot for giving that fiddle link .It helps me a lot .Now question is  updated . Even i found the solution. I should keep all ternary operation inside brackets which i missed for the 1st ternary operation.

Can you please post the same as an answer . I will accept the same.

Comment: No I can't post an answer because this question is already closed.

Comment: I hope that, more than actually finding the answer, that you now appreciate the importance of posting an MCVE from the beginning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should give a compile error since Test is uninitialized in the right hand side! The following should work:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        bool a = true;
        bool b = true;
        bool c = true;
        string x = "";
        string Test = x + (a ? "Clear" : "") + (b ? "Permanent" : "") + (c ? "Salaried" : "");
        Console.WriteLine(Test);

        Console.ReadLine(); //so that my console window doesn't close

    }
```